# Other Open Graph og:type not being parsed correctly by Facebook linter

Tags: facebook

As per Open Graph's documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph , we can specify our own og:types.

> If your object does not fit into one of the types above, you can
>   specify your own type. This will be represented as type other on
>   Facebook. We will monitor the most commonly used types and graduate
>   them to fully supported og:types. If you are specifying your own type
>   we recommend that you use your own namespace.

Running the linter on a page on my website
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fznood.com%2Fachkar_tools returns the following errors:

> Object at URL 'http://znood.com/places/dcGPdl0Psuc' is invalid because
>   the configured 'og:type' of 'znoodcom:store' is invalid

On my other page wich og:type is "city", if you check the linter up top, the og:type is set to "website" (which is bad!)
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=znood.com%2Fcities%2FbIYWj4uRhCc

Can someone clarify how to set up custom types that Open Graph can pick? Also, why is the "city" type being replaced with "website" on my page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try visiting the Open Graph tool inside your app and declare your Object Type.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/define-objects/

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing in your namespace links in your head tag? Like:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# yourns: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/yourns#`">
```

where yourns is your namespace.

Comment: Okay.. Added this to my head (I also have it in my html tag as well, but I didn't have my ns in there). Same errors are still occurring. This is a link to the page I'm using to debug the problem if you care to look :-) http://znood.com/achkar_tools

Comment: Interesting.  When I bring up your namespace url: http://graph.facebook.com/schema/og/fb/znoodcom it returns an error if you look at http://graph.facebook.com/schema/og/fb/xocialize you'll see my defined objects for a project I'm working on.  I'm now thinking there might be a problem with the way your object's are defined in your app or perhaps a FB bug.

Comment: Yes, I checked it but had no clue why that was happening. Paul found the solution below :-) Thanks for your time!